# How to list latest files in a directory using FileNameFilter

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I have a directory which contains xml Files :

```
 20140110-093721565_TOTO.xml
 20140110-093821565_TATA.xml
 20140110-094021565_TOTO.xml
 20140110-091021565_TOTO.xml
 20140110-093921565_TATA.xml
 ....
 20140110-091021565_TETE.xml
```

The first part of the file name represents the time the file was generated : 20140110-09102156

```
 20140110 = Date
 09102156 = Hour
```

and the last part is used to identify the file : TOTO

What I want is to list the last version of each files like :

```
20140110-091021565_TOTO.xml
20140110-093821565_TATA.xml
```

How can I define a FileNameFilter ?

Comment: Read the tutorial on [Finding Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

Comment: Will the files have timestamp same as the names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to provide filter that will restrict the result to just one in your case because the file names are ever variying. Here is one way to acheive what you wanted.

```
File f = new File("C:\\");  // what ever directory you want. 

FilenameFilter totoFilter = new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
    {
        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
        if (lowercaseName.endsWith("TOTO.xml")) return true;
        else                                    return false;

    }
};

FilenameFilter tataFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
        if (lowercaseName.endsWith("TOTO.xml")) return true;
        else                                    return false;
    };

    String[] tataFiles = f.list(tataFilter);
    Arrays.sort(tataFiles, Collections.reverseOrder());

    String[] totoFiles = f.list(totoFilter);
    Arrays.sort(totoFiles, Collections.reverseOrder());

    System.out.println(tataFiles[0]);
    System.out.println(totoFiles[0]);
}
```

I have written an alternative logic that can help you extend what you want to achieve with less number of new lines even when you have to add types. This follows the approach I mentioned in the comment. All you have to do is add new sequence that defines another type of file to array list.

```
    File f = new File("C:\\"); // current directory

    ArrayList<String> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    sequence.add("TATA");
    sequence.add("TOTO");

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
            if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".xml"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    };

    String[] totoFiles = f.list(filter);
    Arrays.sort(totoFiles, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (String type : sequence) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < totoFiles.length; i++) {
            if (totoFiles[i].contains(type))
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(totoFiles[i]);
    }
```

Comment: It's a kind of thing I want to do but 'TOTO' and 'TATA' are examples.

Comment: I understand the fact that TATA and TOTO are example, but there is no way to get it done in a shortcut using FileNameFilter, because you want one file of each kind of file. Alternatively, you can add all files into one array and loop through the array after sorting it and print each time you get a different type of file. I hope you got it.

Comment: I have added second way of doing it as I mentioned in my previous comment, this approach is easier to extend to include other sequence of characters to filter.

Comment: It looks like what I just did. Thank's !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want to do but `DirectoryStream<Path>` can be used to retrieve specific files in a directory. You obtain `DirectoryStream<>` using [the static method of `nio.file.Files` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream) and optionally, you may pass in a glob or a filter to choose what you need / do not need.

Quoting the docs for  [DirectoryStream.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html):

> An interface that is implemented by objects that decide if a directory
>   entry should be accepted or filtered. A Filter is passed as the
>   parameter to the Files.newDirectoryStream(Path,DirectoryStream.Filter)
>   method when opening a directory to iterate over the entries in the
>   directory.

To sum it up, write a custom filter that implements the `DirectoryStream.Filter` interface and put your search criteria logic in `accept()`

Comment: @Remy If you could please post your search criteria then that'd be great ! Post it as an update to your question =)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure It is what you need, but i think you can retrieve data and time from file name, parse it to Date time and get the biggest one, so it will be the last version, right?

Comment: yep, this is what I need, but I was looking for a simple way to do this

Comment: @Remy That's exactly what I am saying. You will need some filtering mechanism of your own. See my answer =)