# How to create a new PDF file if a file name already exists?

Tags: java, filenames

My code below outputs a simple receipt which contains some details from the user like name, fare and stop number. This generates a PDF file containing those details. Whenever a new user inputs data in the main form, this just overwrite the data of the first user in the PDF file. How can I be able to create a new PDF file without appending or overwriting the original data of the first user? (like sample.pdf, sample2.pdf, sample3.pdf...and so on)

```
public class PDFDisplay {

public static void generatePDF(PassengerBean passengerBean) {
     Document document = new Document();

     try {
         final Chunk NEWLINE = new Chunk("\n");
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
              new FileOutputStream("C://sample.pdf"));

          document.open();

          Image img = Image.getInstance("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Pinky\\My Documents\\Angel's files\\ICS 113\\eclipse_ws\\MRTApplicationIteration2\\WebContent\\image\\mrt.jpg");
          document.add(img);

          String or = "Official Receipt";
          String hr = "-----------------------------------------------------------";
          String spacer = " ";
          String name = "Passenger Name: " + passengerBean.lname + "," +  " " + passengerBean.fname;
          String dest = "Destination: " + passengerBean.dest + " STATION";
          String stopno = passengerBean.stop;
          double fare = passengerBean.fare;
          String fare1 = "Fare: PHP" + " " + String.valueOf(fare);
          String ccnum = "CREDIT CARD NUMBER: " + " " + "************" + passengerBean.ccnum.substring(Math.max(0, passengerBean.ccnum.length() - 4));


            Paragraph para10 = new Paragraph(32);
            para10.setSpacingBefore(10);
            para10.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para10.add(new Chunk(or));
            document.add(para10);

            Paragraph para9 = new Paragraph(32);
            para9.setSpacingBefore(30);
            para9.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para9.add(new Chunk(hr));
            document.add(para9);

            // Setting paragraph line spacing to 32
            Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(32);
            para1.setSpacingBefore(5);
            para1.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para1.add(new Chunk(name));
            document.add(para1);

            Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph();
            para2.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para2.add(new Chunk(dest));
            document.add(para2);

            Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph();
            para3.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para3.add(new Chunk(stopno));
            document.add(para3);

            Paragraph para4 = new Paragraph();
            para4.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para4.add(new Chunk(fare1));
            document.add(para4);

            Paragraph para5 = new Paragraph();
            para5.setSpacingAfter(10);
            para5.add(new Chunk(ccnum));
            document.add(para5);


          document.close();

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDF, PDF generation, or iText.

Comment: @Jongware why? I'm generating a PDF file and I'm using the IText library. What tag should I use then?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the methods you might need to achieve what you want can be found in the Java API documentation for the [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

You want to create a **unique** file that starts with `sample` and ends with `pdf`. To achieve this, you can use the [`createTempFile()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)). This question was already answered on StackOverflow 6 years ago: [What is the best way to generate a unique and short file name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825678/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-unique-and-short-file-name-in-java)

Suppose that you really want to have **incremental numbers** in your file name, e.g. sample0001.pdf, sample0002.pdf, sample0003.pdf and so on, then you can use the [`list()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list(java.io.FilenameFilter)). This returns an array of `String` values with the names of all files in a directory. I suggest that you use a `FilenameFilter` so that you only get the PDF files starting with `sample`. You could then sort these names to find the name with the highest number. See [How to list latest files in a directory using FileNameFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236105/how-to-list-latest-files-in-a-directory-using-filenamefilter) to find out how to create such a filter.
Once you have the file name with the highest number, it's only a matter of `String` manipulation to create a new filename. Use that filename (or that `File` instance) when you define the `OutputStream`.

As you can see, this answer doesn't mention iText anywhere and although the extension of the files we create or list is `.pdf`, it has nothing to do with PDF or PDF generation either. It's a pure Java question.